# Vue 3 - Emit in reusable / composable file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use emit in my following file: `useGoo.ts`

```
import Swal from "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js";

export default function useModal() {

  const { emit } = getCurrentInstance();

  function myId() {
    emit('id', '123')
  }

}
```

But the emit does not work ofcourse. Can't get it working. Error:

```
Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'ComponentInternalInstance | null'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define `emit` in your component and then pass it as a parameter into your composable

```js
export default function useModal(emit) {
  function myId() {
    emit('id', '123')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using TypeScript. The solution is as following: `const { emit } = getCurrentInstance() as any;`